# How to get from $\sum_{n=0}^N (a_n \cos{nx} + b_n \sin{nx})$ to $\sum_{-N}^{N} c_n e^{inx}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, online-resources, trigonometric-series

I'm currently reading Baby Rudin, and I'm in the section of Chapter 8 that covers Fourier series. There is one line that I just can't figure out for the life of me, and I can't find anything online about it. He defines trigonometric polynomials as finite sums of the form

$f(x) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^N (a_n \cos{nx} + b_n \sin{nx})$

but then he says that it can be written in the form

$f(x) = \sum_{-N}^{N} c_n e^{inx}$

I just can't figure out the steps here to get from one to the other, specifically why the range is now -N to N. Any pointers here would be super helpful.

In addition, if anyone has recommendations on resources to supplement this section, I would greatly appreciate those as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\cos nx=\frac{e^{inx}+e^{-inx}}2,\quad \sin nx=\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^N (a_n \cos{nx} + b_n \sin{nx})\\\\
&=a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(a_n -ib_n)}2e^{inx}+ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(a_n +ib_n)}2e^{-inx}
\end{align}
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you. I am now only stuck trying to figure out why the indices chage.

Comment: You are welcome. In the second sum, make $m=-n$, giving $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(a_n +ib_n)}2e^{-inx}=\sum_{m=-1}^{-N} \frac{(a_{-m} +ib_{-m})}2e^{imx}$ then collect the two sums (plus $a_0=c_0$) and you are done.