# $a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^N(a_n\cos{nt}+b_n\sin{nt})=\sum\limits_{n=-M}^M c_n e^{int}$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

The more I think about this the less immediately obvious it is. Why exactly are these two synonymous?

Comment: In linear algebra terms, $\{cos (nt), \sin (nt) \}$ and $\{e^{int}, e^{-int}\}$ spans the same 2 dimensional subspaces. Indeed $\cos (nt) = \frac 12(e^{int} + e^{-int})$ and similar for $\sin (nt)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get from $\sum_{n=0}^N (a_n \cos{nx} + b_n \sin{nx})$ to $\sum_{-N}^{N} c_n e^{inx}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753467/how-to-get-from-sum-n-0n-a-n-cosnx-b-n-sinnx-to-sum-nn-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equate the two using Euler's Identity: $$e^{iX} = \cos(X) + i \sin(X).$$

Then \begin{align*}\sum^N_{n=-N} c_ne^{int} &= \sum^N_{n=-N} [c_n\cos(nt) + ic_n\sin(nt)] \\
&= c_0 + \sum^N_{n=1} \big[c_n\cos(nt) +ic_n\sin(nt) + c_{-n}\cos(-nt) + ic_{-n}\sin(-nt)\big]\\
&=c_0 + \sum^N_{n=1} \big[(c_n + c_{-n})\cos(nt) + i(c_n - c_{-n})\sin(nt)\big].  
\end{align*} Thus the two representations are equivalent under the relationships $$a_0 = c_0, \,\,\,\,\, a_n = c_n + c_{-n}, \,\,\,\,\, b_n = i(c_n - c_{-n}).$$